# How to make transparent water at unity shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, transparent

I have mesh and want to make water effect on it and see inside of water. I am new unity shader so I dont know how can I do in Unity shader ?

Comment: https://alexanderameye.github.io/simple-water.html

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to create your own shader but with minimal effort** and a graphical user interface, you can look into Unity [Shader Graph](https://unity.com/shader-graph). There are plenty of tutorials available online.

**If you want to write your own shader from scratch**, it may be best to look for YouTube tutorials or [Unity Documentation on writing shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadersOverview.html)